# WatiN can't find text after searching google

Tags: watin

I'm trying to run a simple watiN example: search google then verify the search result. (on IE9)

```
var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com/ncr");

browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();

Assert.True(browser.ContainsText("WatiN"));
```

This test fails! I don't know why, but adding a call to WaitUntilContainsText("Everything") make this pass:

```
var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com/ncr");

browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
browser.WaitUntilContainsText("Everything");// because of google instant??
browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();

Assert.True(browser.ContainsText("WatiN"));
```

I guess this maybe because of the behavior of google instant but can't be sure.
Can someone explain what's wrong with this test?

Comment: I recently ran this example using WatiN, and ran into some trouble because the search button's name is now "BtnK" instead of "BtnG"

Comment: I've just checked this. It's actually 2 ids for 2 google pages: btnK: on the google home page (where there's 1 long textbox in the middle of the screen). This time the button's id = 'gbqfa'. btnG: on the google result page (where the main textbox is on top of the screen. This time the button's id = 'gbqfb'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it has to do with Google Instant. When you call `Click()` on button the page will not be reloaded, so the call to `ContainsText` will occur almost without delay. You need to use some `Wait...` methods of the `IE` or elements if you are browsing pages generated by javascript on the fly (AJAX mostly).

Comment: Thank you. It seems that there's no single method to wait for ajax call to complete. I've seen some solutions that apply for .aspx but not for google ajax.