# MSTest + WatiN simple button click fails

Tags: button, visual-studio-2012, mstest, watin

I am trying to get MSTest and WatiN to play nicely together.  I have a simple sample test that just pulls up google and hits the search button.  When debugging the test, it works as expected.  When running the test inside Visual Studio 2012, the WatiN script fails to click the button. It seems like the button is found but the click event does not occur.   I have tried to do Click and Wait and some other things.  The code is given below:

```
[TestMethod]
public void web2()
{
    bool hasText;
    IE ie = IEStaticInstanceHelper.IE;
    ie.GoTo("http://www.google.com");
    ie.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("Dixie");
    Button bt1 = ie.Button(Find.ByName("btnK"));
    bt1.Click();
    hasText = ie.ContainsText("Dixie");
    Assert.IsTrue(hasText, @"The search result does not contain text ""Dixie"".");
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816267/watin-cant-find-text-after-searching-google

Comment: Thanks, actually it looks like it was a misuderstanding of how the google initial seach was working with the tools.  So this solved my issues.   Thanks!